# Replicate a string names x times and ascribe replication number

Tags: awk

I would like to replicate key names x number of times and have a separate column to indicate the replication number, e.g. let's say I have three key names as follows:

```
101
102
103
```

So, I would like each of the above numbers (names) replicated 3 times and to have a separate identifier number equal to 4 characters. It would therefore look like this:

```
101  0001
101  0002
101  0003
102  0001
102  0002
102  0003
103  0001
103  0002
103  0003
```

I guess this could be genered with a relatively straight forward awk script? *Edit: I would like to not specify the names to replicate in the script - it should be "replicate all names in this text file", as there are a lot of them (~400) and all with variable name types.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: could `x` be greater than 10, 100, 1000?  if yes, is there further requirement of the number format of the later `01,02...`?

Comment: No, the x number of times will be 80 in this case and all 4 characters long (i.e. 0001, 0002 etc.).

Answer (score 1):

In bash

```
echo {101,102,103}" "{01,02,03}

101 01 101 02 101 03 102 01 102 02 102 03 103 01 103 02 103 03
```

Following Fedorqui's advice for newlines

```
printf "%s\n" {101,102,103}" "{01,02,03}

101 01 
101 02 
101 03 
102 01 
102 02 
102 03 
103 01 
103 02 
103 03
```

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {101,102,103}" "{01,02,03}` to have new lines

Comment: @fedorqui Did OP want newlines ? I can't see any indication before your edit that they do ? Actually after their edit now i have no idea what they want !

Comment: Are you really asking this? Haven't you seen hundreds of times people posting some code and not formatting it with the tools, so that it looks like it is the same line? Well, this appears to be another case. Also, see the OP says _and have a separate column_, so in a unique row it wouldn't make sense. I just edited to show what the OP wrote without format.

Comment: @fedorqui I was looking at the markdown, instead of the source so it looked like it was on the same line but yes that is apparent now. I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: So how would the printf command work in order to specify all line inputs rather than writing them out manually?

Comment: @DanielClemence It won't, that wasn't in the question when i wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `awk` `-v` flag to pass a variable `number` which is the number of repeats for each line, and `sprint` to format the number into 2 decimal places with zero padding:

```
awk -v number_repeats=3 '{
  for(i=0; i<number_repeats; i++) { 
    print $0, sprintf("%02d", i+1) 
  } 
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I realised something I did not make clear in my original post: I have 400 different key names to repeat. So in the script I need to say "replicate all". What would it need to be changed to for that?

Comment: If run on your example input, this will produce the example output. I don't understand your clarification. If there are 400 lines in the files, it will do the same thing to each line, there is nothing hardcoded

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to check this. I can see the script has $0, meaning it is applied to all lines, so I think this will work fine - thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, $0 just means the current line, awk will iterate over all lines in files by default. Feel free to accept this answer if it ends up solving your problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind GNU Parallel

```
parallel -k 'printf "%02d %02d\n"' ::: {6..12} ::: 1 2 3
06 01
06 02
06 03
07 01
07 02
07 03
08 01
08 02
08 03
09 01
09 02
09 03
10 01
10 02
10 03
11 01
11 02
11 03
12 01
12 02
12 03
```

Or, if your keys are in a file, called `keys` like this

```
32
45
78
```

You can read the file

```
parallel -k 'printf "%02d %02d\n" {1} {2}' :::: keys ::: 1 2 3
32 01
32 02
32 03
45 01
45 02
45 03
78 01
78 02
78 03
```